# REACT: Conditional display if empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render(){
    return(
        <div className="person">
             <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.name}}/>
             <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.age}}/>
        </div>
)
}
```

Currently only showing name and age (both are strings). Is there a way to check if name is empty, then age will also be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know that item is so you can conditionally render them like this. This will mean the div will only render if the value is true.

```js
render(){
    return(
        <div className="person">
           {item.name && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.name}}/>}
           {item.age && <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.age}}/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, should've specified that item is an input array map.

Comment: Do you mean it is an object? seems a bit odd if it is an array.
I also just reread your question and didnt realise you wanted both of them to be hidden if name is empty so I have just done an edit

Comment: Ah yes it's an object. Is there a way to set them both to empty as opposed to null?

Comment: im confused about what you are asking. Youve asked `Is there a way to check if name is empty, then age will also be empty?` That is telling me that if name is empty you dont want either to show. Thats what is happening above. If there isnt a name, then nothing with render.

Comment: There's a bunch of other code that needs to run before the <div className="person"> which I've omitted. Returning null would just stop the other code from running no?

Comment: Just did another edit. You really should of said that in your question. In the future you need to give as much context as possible. People are going to answer the question based on the info which you have provided in the question (which is what I did). If I knew there were more code then I would have given this answer at the beginning.

Comment: Will do for the future and apologies for the trouble. Thanks!!